# Adding BroadcastReceiver to FirebaseMessagingServices

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-broadcastreceiver

I am having some problems with `FirebaseMessagingServices`.

I have a project with two apps, where we can send data messages (notification with payloads) from one app to another. They are working fine when they are in foreground and when they are in background they receive messages but only upto 30min of interval.

I mean to say is if the app is killed, after around 30min or an hour it doesnt receive messages. I think they are disconnecting from `Firebase` after 30 minutes and i dont want that to happen . If it is disconnecting, then it should reconnect to `Firebase` itself untill there is internet connection in mobile.

I researched a lot and finally landed on `BROADCAST` receivers. They work even if the app is killed. So how can i use `Broadcast` receivers to reconnect with `Firebase` as soon as they are disconnected?

Here are my classes:

**MyFirebaseMessaging**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessaging extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(final RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    if (remoteMessage.getData() != null) {
        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
        String title = data.get("title");
        final String companyName = data.get("CompanyName");
        final String BookingIdC = data.get("BookingIdC");
        final String BookingIdT = data.get("BookingIdT");
        final String companyPhone = data.get("CompanyPhone");
        final String companyRates = data.get("CompanyRates");
        final String companyId = data.get("CompanyId");
        final String Date = data.get("Date");
        final String companyIdC = data.get("companyIdC");
        final String Time = data.get("Time");
        final String Id = data.get("Id");
        final String Address = data.get("Address");
        final String Bookingid = data.get("Bookingid");
        final String TimeCB = data.get("TimeCB");
        final String DateCB = data.get("DateCB");
        final String EventType = data.get("EventType");
        final String messageCB = data.get("messageCB");
        final String AddressCB = data.get("AddressCB");
        final String companythatcancelledthebooking = data.get("CompanyNamethatcancelledthebooking");

        final String message = data.get("message");
        //  remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle() = title and  remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody() = message
        if (title != null && title.equals("Cancel")) {
            Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MyFirebaseMessaging.this, DeclinedWindow.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);

                    Common.isCompanyFound = false;
                    Common.companyId = "";
                    Toast.makeText(MyFirebaseMessaging.this, "" + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } else if (title != null && title.equals("cancelAdvanceBooking")) {
            Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), CompanycancelledtheBooking.class);
                    intent.putExtra("DateCB", DateCB);
                    intent.putExtra("TimeCB", TimeCB);
                    intent.putExtra("messageCB", messageCB);
                    intent.putExtra("AddressCB", AddressCB);
                    intent.putExtra("EventType", EventType);
                    intent.putExtra("Id", Id);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                    startActivity(intent);

                    Common.isCompanyFound = false;
                    Common.companyId = "";
                    Toast.makeText(MyFirebaseMessaging.this, "" + messageCB, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        } else if (title != null && title.equals("Accept")) {


            Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MyFirebaseMessaging.this, AcceptedWindow.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Date", Date);
                    intent.putExtra("Time", Time);
                    intent.putExtra("Address", Address);
                    intent.putExtra("companyName", companyName);
                    intent.putExtra("companyPhone", companyPhone);
                    intent.putExtra("companyRates", companyRates);
                    intent.putExtra("companyId", companyId);
                    intent.putExtra("Bookingid", Bookingid);
                    intent.putExtra("EventType", EventType);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                    startActivity(intent);
                    Common.isCompanyFound = false;
                    Common.companyId = "";


                    Toast.makeText(MyFirebaseMessaging.this, "" + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        } else if (title != null && title.equals("Arrived")) {
            Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                        showArrivedNotifAPI26(message);
                    else
                        showArrivedNotif(message);

                }
            });
        } else if (title != null && title.equals("Completed")) {

            openRateactivity(message);
        } else if (title != null && title.equals("completedAdvancebooking")) {
            Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MyFirebaseMessaging.this, VerifyingCompletedBooking.class);
                    intent.putExtra("BookingIdC", BookingIdC);
                    intent.putExtra("message", message);
                    intent.putExtra("companyid", companyIdC);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
        } else if (title != null && title.equals("Ontheway")) {
            Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MyFirebaseMessaging.this, Onthewayandimreached.class);
                    intent.putExtra("message", message);
                    intent.putExtra("BookingIdT", BookingIdT);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
        } else if (title != null && title.equals("Reached")) {
            Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MyFirebaseMessaging.this, Onthewayandimreached.class);
                    intent.putExtra("message", message);
                    intent.putExtra("BookingIdT", BookingIdT);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
        }

    }
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void showArrivedNotifAPI26(String body) {
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0,
            new Intent(), PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationHelper notificationHelper = new NotificationHelper(getBaseContext());
    Notification.Builder builder = notificationHelper.getUberNotification("Arrived", body, contentIntent, defaultSound);
    notificationHelper.getManager().notify(1, builder.build());

}

private void openRateactivity(String body) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, RateActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private void showArrivedNotif(String body) {
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0,
            new Intent(), PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext());
    builder.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()).
            setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera)
            .setContentTitle("Arrived")
            .setContentText(body)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(1, builder.build());
}
```

**MyFirebaseIdService**

```
    public class MyFirebaseIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
        @Override
        public void onTokenRefresh() {
            super.onTokenRefresh();

            String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
            updateTokenToServer(refreshedToken);

        }

        private void updateTokenToServer(String refreshedToken) {

            FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            DatabaseReference tokens = db.getReference(Common.token_table);

            Token token = new Token(refreshedToken);
            if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null)
                tokens.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(token);

        }
    }
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.praful.ubercoustomer">

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.accountkit.ApplicationName"
            android:value="@string/app_name" />
        <meta-data xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/FACEBOOK_APP_ID"
            tools:replace="android:value" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.accountkit.ClientToken"
            android:value="@string/ACCOUNT_KIT_CLIENT_TOKEN" />

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
       <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Home"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

        <service
            android:name=".Service.MyFirebaseIdService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".Service.MyFirebaseMessaging"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity android:name=".RateActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".CallCompany" />
        <activity
            android:name=".DeclinedWindow"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".AcceptedWindow"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".AdvanceBookings"
            android:parentActivityName=".Home"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity android:name=".CompanyInfo" />
        <activity android:name=".AdvanceBookingsDetails" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CompanycancelledtheBooking"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CancelledBookings"
            android:parentActivityName=".Home"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity android:name=".VerifyingCompletedBooking" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CompletedBookings"
            android:parentActivityName=".Home"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Onthewayandimreached"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".RateactivityforAdvanceBooking"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CallCompanyforAdvanceBooking"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_call_companyfor_advance_booking"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Howtouse"
            android:parentActivityName=".Home"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity android:name=".Listofavailablecompanies" />
        <activity android:name=".Availablecompanydetails"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I need help implementing a `BroadcastReciever` in between a service and a activity (`FirebaseMesssaging` Services --> `Broadcastreceiver` --> `Activity`).

What i want is , app should be connected to `FirebaseMessagingServices` 24/7 (even when the app is killed and dead for hours) just like `Whatsapp` or `Uber` or `youtube` app, they send notifications even when i killed them for some hours ago.

Not that i want help only from `Broadcasts`; If there is any other way to do it please share it with me.